# How to get value at a given index of a QTableView

Tags: qt, qt4, qtableview

I am working in Qt 4.7, and I have a fully populated QTableView of variable number of rows and set number of columns. I have a QStringList which I need to populate with the value from a specific column, let's say the second, of each row. So far I have this:

```
QStringList list;

for (int i = 0; i < ui->myTableView->height()/*see note below*/; i++)
{
      list.append(/*code I still need...*/);
}
```

//note: I also tried it using this->ui->myTableView->model->rowCount(), not sure which is best for this...

My problem is that I can't find any function that will allow me to get the value in a QTableView given the row and column number. I don't know if I'm just overlooking it, but I've been going through the docs and can't seem to find anything. If anyone's got any ideas I'd really appreciate the help. Thanks!

Comment: You need to have table model from which data is displayed in this view and iterate through items in model

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could try this:

```
QStringList list;
QAbstractItemModel *model = ui->myTableView->model();

for(int i = 0; i < model->rowCount(); i++)
{
    QModelIndex index = model->index(i, 0); // The first column data.
    list.append(index.data().toString());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, quick question though, how would the function know which column to take data from? (never mind, just saw the edit)

Comment: @thnkwthprtls You pass the column number to it. [See the docs](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qabstractitemmodel.html#index).